# why is line-clamp not working with padding?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to line-clamp 3 lines, but for some reason when I add padding it doesn't seem to work and moves to 4 lines like this:

```css
.title{
  padding:1rem;
  width:10%;
  background-color:red;
  word-break: break-all;

  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='title'>
  Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
</div>
```

How do I fix it?

**Edit:**

My apologies, I forgot to mention I require border at the bottom like this:

```css
.title{
  padding:1rem;
  width:10%;
  background-color:red;
  word-break: break-all;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: hidden;
}

.title:nth-of-type(1){
  border-bottom:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class='title'>
  Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
</div>

<div class='title'>
  Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
</div>
```

I'm hoping that I won't have to wrap it around another div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a transparent border instead

```css
.title{
  border:1rem solid #0000;
  box-shadow:0 1px 0 #000; /* your border */
  margin-bottom:1px;
  width:10%;
  background-color:red;
  word-break: break-all;

  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='title'>
  Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add that I need border at the bottom, I've edited the question now

Answer (score 7):

`line-clamp` is just clamping the text after set lines. But it is not removing text from the dom.

For example, `line-clamp: 3` results in the following:

```
Hello World
This is
An Exammple...
For this Post
```

This is why we add an `overflow: hidden;` to hide it.

But an padding will make your box bigger, so the `overflow` is only happing after your padding.

A solution can be to wrap your title in an wrapper div and set the padding there.

*Snippet contains an example without the overflow, for visualiziation*

```css
.title{
  padding:1rem;
  width:10%;
  background-color:red;
  word-break: break-all;

  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class='title'>
  Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
</div>
```

Comment: I was actually hoping to avoid having to wrap it around another div but thank you for the explanation :)